# Can I use Thymeleaf templates + bindings without sticky sessions?

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf, high-availability

I currently use a HA-Setup without sticky sessions. Is it generally possible to use thymeleaf templates with bound objects in non-sticky-sessions?

I am not familiar with the inner workings of thymeleaf -- neither do I have an idea how to test this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thymeleaf would work with the data which you put in your Spring model object. So the scope of that data is that of the request. And moreover, Thymeleaf templates are processed at the server. So the flow is:

- User requests for a URL
- Spring framework receives it at the server and routes it to the controller
- the controller executes the method mapped. This might involve populating the Model or ModelMap object and returns either the view template name or the Model object
- the view resolver retrieves the view template name and uses the corresponding view template engine to process the HTML in the view template name and then return the HTML to the response
- this response is then sent to the user

So you see there is no sessions involved. But when you use Spring Security, it would use session to record the authenticated user information. 
And if the user explicitly uses session in their code then it would be a problem.

Comment: thank you for the detailed answer; it cleared up a lot of misunderstandings on my end.